# Python docx AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, python-docx

I want to insert about 250 images with their filename into a docx-file.

My `test.py` file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import docx
from docx.shared import Cm

filepath = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\img"
document = docx.Document()

for file in Path(filepath).iterdir():
#    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(Path(file).resolve().stem)
    document.add_picture(Path(file).absolute(), width=Cm(15.0))

document.save('test.docx')
```

After Debugging I got this Error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'seek'
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    document.add_picture(Path(file).absolute(), width=Cm(15.0))
```

How can i avoid this Error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [io.FileIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO)?

```
from io import FileIO

from pathlib import Path
import docx
from docx.shared import Cm

filepath = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\img"
document = docx.Document()

for file in Path(filepath).iterdir():
#    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(Path(file).resolve().stem)
    document.add_picture(FileIO(Path(file).absolute(), "rb"), width=Cm(15.0))

document.save('test.docx')
```

I encountered the same error using PyPDF2 when passing a file path to PdfFileReader. When I wrapped the PDF file in `FileIO` like so `FileIO(pdf_path, "rb")` the error went away and I was able to process the file successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the file object to a string type for the Path method.

```
for file in Path(filepath).iterdir():
# Paragraph = document.add_paragraph(Path(file).resolve().stem)
    document.add_picture(Path(str(file)).absolute(), width=Cm(15.0))
```

Comment: This solved a similar issue for me - just put a str() around the file variable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is within `python-docx` (still) as of the current version 0.8.11 (from 31/03/2022). Wherein the assumption is that if it's not a string, it must be a file operator. This is an unfortunate limitation of docx design, surely a holdover from pre-Pathlib days, as `Path` objects have an open method to directly use them as a file operator, and would work as well as `str` [if they weren't being filtered out with an `is_string` test](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/36cac78de080d412e9e50d56c2784e33655cad59/docx/image/image.py#L39).

So in order to work around it, you need to pass in a string. Fortunately, pathlib has good coverage for this. Change your loop to pass in the file name. Also, you're already using Path, so skip the raw strings for your `filepath`

```
filepath = Path("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/img")
# filepath = Path(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\img") # alternatively, gives same results
document = docx.Document()

for file in filepath.iterdir():
#    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(Path(file).resolve().stem)
    document.add_picture(file.as_posix(), width=Cm(15.0))
```

Additionally, if you want to scrub relative pathing, *do not* use `absolute()`, use `resolve()`.

In this case however, you know the files exist. You setup an absolute `filepath`, so the full path is guaranteed, there is no need for `resolve()` (or `absolute()`).

If instead your filepath was relative, you could resolve it once to avoid the overhead of handling each file that comes out of `iterdir()`

```
filepath = Path("Desktop/img")
# filepath = Path(r"Desktop\img") # alternatively, gives same results
document = docx.Document()
full_filepath = filepath.resolve() # to Path("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/img")
# filepath = filepath.resolve() # is also safe

for file in full_filepath.iterdir():
#    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(Path(file).resolve().stem)
    document.add_picture(file.as_posix(), width=Cm(15.0))
```

But when it's not certain: `resolve()` will remove any `'..'` that may enter into your paths. Behavior on Windows can be unpredictable when the location doesn't exist, but as long as the file (including dirs) already exists, `resolve()` will give you a full, absolute path. If the file doesn't exist, then it will bizarrely only add a full path on Windows if there are relative steps like `'..'` in the path. On the other hand, `absolute()` never scrubs `'..'` but will always add a root path on Windows, so if you need to be sure, you could call `absolute()` first and then `resolve()`, and lastly `as_posix()` for a string: `file.absolute().resolve().as_posix()`

But be warned: [`absolute()` is not documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods), so its behavior could change or be removed without warning.

As others have written, you can also use `str(file)`. Since Path stores posix safe path-strings, you should find `str(file) == file.as_posix()` is True in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, changing the '/' for '\' in the path did the trick. Ex: "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/img" 
(which I believe is probably what wrapping it in FileIO does, but in my case doing this didn't work)

You can also achieve that using

```
os.path.join(mydir, myfile)
```

as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/11126742

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast the path object to string:

```
for file in Path(filepath).iterdir():
    path_str = str(Path(file).absolute())
    document.add_picture(path_str, width=Cm(15.0))
```

The problem with using WindowsPath object as an input seems to be that the *document.add_picture* does not know how to use that to open a file. The *seek* is a method of a file object.